# Touchbar MBP with broken screen won't display on external monitor

Tags: mac, display, startup, screen, touch-bar

I have a Macbook Pro, not sure which year but it's Intel-based with a touchbar and 4 USB-C/Thunderbolt connectors. Recently the screen broke, and the Mac by itself is completely unusable. The computer still makes all the typical noises, and I can still press buttons. I'm using a USB hub to connect the monitor, mouse and keyboard to the computer.

I am able to access Recovery Assistant, and, when I do, the external screen goes gray and I am able to see the mouse pointer. I am then able to put the Mac into chamshell mode and I can then view Recovery Assistant on the external screen. However, for some reason, I am unable to then restart the computer in chamshell mode. The external screen does not go gray when I restart the computer, instead turning black, and then the external screen proclaims that there is "no signal" and proceeds to turn off, despite the fact that it is still plugged into the Mac and I can see and hear that the Mac is on.

One time, I was lucky I guess, and I was somehow able to force the Mac into clamshell mode on startup. The external screen showed the typical login page, allowing me to log in. However, after I chose a Wifi network, I got an error:

*A critical software update is required for your Mac, but an error was encountered while installing this update.
Your Mac can't be used until this update is installed.
[Shut down] [try again]*

I tried again and again, to no avail. I eventually shut it down. After some internet digging I think the issue is that some software pertaining to the touchbar isn't downloaded, and it's very possible that issue would be resolved by putting the Mac into safe mode. However, when I hold shift upon restart, the computer turns on, but there is no indicator that I actually booted it into safe mode (I wouldn't be able to see the red corner text anyway), and the external screen is still being finicky and refusing to recognize the Mac as existent, again proclaiming that there is no signal. I am still able to access Recovery Assistant on the external screen.

It must be possible to view to the login page on the external screen; I already did it once, but I have no idea what I did to achieve that.

Perhaps I would be able to access the Mac in target disk mode, but at that point I would have to buy a new Mac anyway and I really want to avoid that...

Help? I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store: they will tell you what is wrong, what needs to be fixed and how much it will cost. You can then make a decision about whether to invest in that Mac before getting a new one. (It's better to sell a working machine.) Yours is between 2017 to 2020, so still a decent Mac.